# Oracle 12c export and import schema with different data tablespace and index tablespace

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, import, export, tablespaces

Suppose that I exported the schema objects from my Oracle 12c database using the original export utility as below:

```
exp userid=<export_schema_name>/<export_schema_password>@<db_string> file=<file_name>.dmp statistics=none log=<file_name>.log
```

The export_schema_name uses different tablespaces for data and indexes, let's called data_tbs_1 and idx_tbs_1. All tables in the export_schema_name are created as below:

```
create table <table_name>
(
    -- columns definition
)
tablespace <data_tbs_1>
/
--
alter table <table_name>
add constraint <constraint_name> primary key(<key_name>)
using index tablespace <idx_tbs_1>
```

Now I want to import the exported dump file into a new schema that I created as below (I already created a new data tablespace data_tbs_2):

```
create user <import_schema_name> identified by <import_schema_password>
default tablespace <data_tbs_2>
```

The imporst command I am going to use is:

```
imp userid=SYSTEM/<import_system_password>@<db_string> file=<file_name>.dmp statistics=none log=<file_name>.log fromuser=<export_schema_name> touser=<import_schema_name>
```

My questions are:

1. If I do this, where are the data and indexes in  stored? Are they still in the data_tbs_1 and idx_tbs_1 **or** they all in the data_tbs_2.
2. If the indexes of the  are still stored in idx_tbs_1, how do I switch them to a new index tablespace (say idx_tbs_2) that I will create?

Comment: Why do you want to use the old export tool? From a comment I learned that you want to import to or export from  a database with lower version. So what do you want to do, what version are involved and what happens if you try this out for a single table with an index?

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why would you use EXP when you have EXPDP-more efficient and performant tool- on your hand?

**Using IMPDP**

> If I do this, where are the data and indexes in stored? Are they still
>   in the data_tbs_1 and idx_tbs_1 or they all in the data_tbs_2.

Yes. Since the import job executes the DDL to create those tables and the DDL includes `TABLESPACE` clause to define where to create the table not the default tablespace of the user. The objects will be created in their original tablespace regardless of the default tablespace of the new user.

This can be confirmed by exporting the dump file to SQL file. 
`IMPDP` Command-

```
impdp system@orclpdb directory=dp_dir dumpfile=expdp_jay.dmp sqlfile=jay_ddl.sql
```

DDL-

Here is an excerpt from the SQL file.

```
CREATE TABLE "JAY"."TBL1"
   (    "TEXT" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ; -- Here you can see it has defined the tablespace to create the table.
```

> If the indexes of the are still stored in idx_tbs_1, how do I switch them to a new index tablespace (say idx_tbs_2) that I will create?

You can use `REMAP_TABLESPACE` parameter while importing the dump.

Here is the DDL for the same table imported with the `REMAP_TABLESPACE` clause.

IMPDP command-

```
impdp system@orclpdb directory=dp_dir dumpfile=expdp_jay.dmp sqlfile=jay2_ddl.sql remap_tablespace=USERS:DATA
```

DDL-

```
CREATE TABLE "JAY"."TBL1"
   (    "TEXT" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "DATA" ;
```

[REMAP_TABLESPACE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-F467946E-50B3-4CC0-937A-CC8C18AAF8C1.htm#SUTIL929)

Update:

> The reason I still use the original exp and imp utilities is because my company still have that legacy data on previous version Oracle database.

If that is the case, I would import the objects in the same tablespace and later on I would migrate to another tablespace using `ALTER INDEX REBUILD TABLESPACE <new_tbs>` command.

**Using IMP**

If you have to use the original import tool then-

- First of all, you need to extract the DDL from the dump file using
  [indexfile](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96652/ch02.htm)
  parameter along with `fromuser` and `touser` parameter(Same schema name for `fromuser` and `touser`).

Example: `imp system@orclpdb file=dumpfile.dmp fromuser=jay touser=jay indexfile=DDL.sql`
Note: It takes some efforts to edit the SQL file which contains `REM` keywords as well as output for the number of rows.

Sample:

```
[oracle@oracdbuat fra]$ cat DDL.sql

REM  CREATE TABLE "JAY"."EMP2" ("ID" NUMBER) PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40
REM  INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 TABLESPACE "DATALRG" LOGGING NOCOMPRESS ;
REM  ... 0 rows
REM  CREATE TABLE "JAY"."EMPLOYEE" ("ID" NUMBER) PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40
REM  INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS
REM  1 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT) TABLESPACE
REM  "USERS" LOGGING NOCOMPRESS ;
REM  ... 0 rows
```

- Edit the SQL file generated by the import tool to change the
  tablespace for the objects.
- Run the SQL script using SQLPLUS.
- Disable all the constraints
- Import the dump file with the parameter `IGNORE=Y` to ignore the
  warning about the already existed objects.
- Enable the constraints.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The reason I still use the original exp and imp utilities is because my company still have that legacy data on previous version Oracle database. Does the remap_tablespace method works on original imp utility? Also, from the DDL created when using the impdb utility, it seems that it remaps only data tablespace. Can I also remap the index tablespace because my tables also use the "using index tablespace" clause.

Comment: concerning the  old exp/imp: No, the index file does not contain the ddl of the objects of the dump, it contains only the ddl of the indexes of the dump.There is the SHOW=YES option you can try to create SQL statements, but  this needs some edit of this file before you can run it with sqlplus. Maybe there is a better approach then creating the objects with sqlplus. How do you know that the OP wants to import in an 8i Oracle?

Comment: @miracle173: Thanks. Yeah, `indexfile` alone is not enough to generate DDL for both tables and indexes.  According to OP's comment, "The reason I still use the original exp and imp utilities is because my company still have that legacy data on previous version Oracle database", I outlined the solution. I would love to know if it is possible to use `impdp` to import the dump file exported using `exp`. I didn't mention that he has to import it in Oracle 8i. Instead, I said if OP needs to use `imp` to import the dump file exported using `exp`.

Comment: It is not possible to use  impdp to import a dumpfile created by exp. You refeferenced th Oracle 8i manual so I assumed it is an import to an 8i database